# Visual Studio 2015 fresh install, errors

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've just decided to install VS2015 Professional and I'm getting a ton of errors when running it. I've trying running a repair, also did an /uninstall /force and reinstall from both the ISO and Web Installer but with no luck. I'm running as administrator.

Most of the errors are on load, "The 'xxxx' package did not load correctly"

I've seen that a lot of people with this problem just delete ComponentModelCache and it fixes it. I've tried this also but no luck.

Also when I try to close VS2015 I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error, I also get that when selecting certain options from menus.

Here is most of the errors I'm getting

[image: VS2015 Errors]

This is an entry from the ActivityLog

```
 <entry>
    <record>493</record>
    <time>2015/08/11 12:22:53.169</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [NuGetPackage]</description>
    <guid>{5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC}</guid>
    <hr>80004003 - E_POINTER</hr>
    <errorinfo>Object reference not set to an instance of an object.</errorinfo>
  </entry>
```

All of the packages that fail, fail with "SetSite failed ...."

I'm using Windows 8.1, i have VS2010, 2012, 2013 installed too.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Steve

Comment: {5FCC8577-4FEB-4D04-AD72-D6C629B083CC} should be NuGet. Install the latest version and look what happens.

Comment: Maybe the file NuGet.config in %appdata%\nuget\ is empty? Paste following into: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>

Comment: It isn't just nuget that was just an example of the error. Nuget is configured ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep this short, the problem was left over files from a Visual Studio Preview Installed.

**Here is how I fixed the problem.**

1. Uninstalled the current VS2015 Pro installed which was not working.
   It left a bunch of files/folders in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
   Visual Studio 14.0\ which i assume are actually from the preview
   version.
2. Rebooted my machine
3. Deleted everything inside C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio 14.0\
4. Installed VS2015 Pro
5. Rebooted
6. Repaired VS2015 Pro
7. Rebooted

I posted the answer on my question over @ MSDN Forum here: [MSDN Forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54d52883-2d48-447b-bd1e-c954dc50ad2a/visual-studio-2015-fresh-install-errors?forum=vssetup#b21dbd51-ccd2-4086-ae6f-5b8fa2f3a153)

Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks

Steve